# Check Uploaded File Extension on PHP Form

Tags: php, forms

I'm have a PHP contact for that checks for errors in a submission. At one part, I check the file upload for specific extensions.  If the extensions isn't allowed (i.e. PHP file), then the form should produce an error message (and NOT upload the file). All of my other error message work, except this one.  Please take a look at the code below and let me know if you see the problem (cause I can't see what is wrong)

```
// *** FILE UPLOAD INFO *** //
//Get the uploaded file information
$name_of_uploaded_file =
    basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
//get the file extension of the file
$type_of_uploaded_file =
    substr($name_of_uploaded_file,
    strrpos($name_of_uploaded_file, '.') + 1);
$size_of_uploaded_file =
    $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"]/1024;//size in KBs

//FILE UPLOAD
        //Settings
        $max_allowed_file_size = 5000; // size in KB
        $allowed_extensions = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "bmp", "png", "zip", "pdf", "doc", "rtf");
        // Validations
        if($size_of_uploaded_file > $max_allowed_file_size )
        {
          $errors .= "<li>Size of file should be less than $max_allowed_file_size </li>";
        }
        //------ Validate the file extension -----
        $allowed_ext = 0;
        for($i=0; $i<sizeof($allowed_extensions); $i++)
        {
          if(strcasecmp($allowed_extensions[$i],$type_of_uploaded_file) == 0)
          {
            $allowed_ext = 1;
          }
        }

        if($allowed_ext==1)
        {
          $errors .= "<li>The uploaded file is not supported file type</li>";
          // " Only the following file types are supported: ".implode(',',$allowed_extensions);
        }

       // Check for Errors
       if(strlen($error_message) > 0) { // Check length of error message
          $errors=1; // There are Errors
       }
```

Comment: Are you looping through the extensions array and comparing the values? Why don't you use the `in_array` or `array_key_exists` function? Another thing - Where have you defined `$type_of_uploaded_file`? Consider that `type` isn't the same as `extension`.

Comment: How are you getting $type_of_uploaded_file?

Comment: I added some more of my PHP code, to explain where the type_of_uploaded_file is coming from. I'm not great with PHP (hence why I'm asking for help). Fred, I'll expand the array used in the loop to account for capitalization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer. The .errors variable was conflicting with another one earlier in the form. So, it was not validating the error. Got it working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have inverted the conditional so that, if your `if` syntax is correct, it will give you the contrast result. i.e if it is a `php` file will be uploaded, but `jpg` will be not. So I prefer to make `$allowed_ext` a Boolean value. i.e true or false, the way of setting it as 0 or 1 may cause confusion and need may need other operators.

```
$allowed_ext = false;
        for($i=0; $i<sizeof($allowed_extensions); $i++)
        {
          if(strcasecmp($allowed_extensions[$i],$type_of_uploaded_file) == 0)
          {
            $allowed_ext = true;
          }
        }

        if(!$allowed_ext)
        {
          $errors .= "<li>The uploaded file is not supported file type</li>";
          // " Only the following file types are supported: ".implode(',',$allowed_extensions);
        }....
```

Comment: I replaced the portion of code with what you recommend ... but the code still lets me upload PHP files (which I am trying to avoid). In fact, it also lets me upload JPG files as well. So, the "check" isn't working somewhere. I'm going to try and comment out some variables ...

Comment: Got it.  It was a problem with the error string and validating it. A mix-up on my part.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
Simply use in_array(), replace your code with new one

// your code to be replaced    
//------ Validate the file extension -----

    $allowed_ext = 0;
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($allowed_extensions); $i++)
    {
      if(strcasecmp($allowed_extensions[$i],$type_of_uploaded_file) == 0)
      {
        $allowed_ext = 1;
      }
    }

    if($allowed_ext==1)
    {
      $errors .= "<li>The uploaded file is not supported file type</li>";
      // " Only the following file types are supported: ".implode(',',$allowed_extensions);
    }


// new code
//------  Validate the file extension -----

if(!in_array($type_of_uploaded_file,$allowed_extensions))
{
    $errors .= "<li>The uploaded file is not supported file type</li>";         
}
```